# Как присвоить auto_increment значение переменной?

Tags: php, mysql

При удалении из таблицы элемента с максимальным id, auto_increment должен стать равным max(`id`).

```
$MaxId = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query(
  $CONNECT, 'SELECT max(`id`) FROM `load`'));
//$MaxId[0] — максимальный id в таблице
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "DELETE FROM `load` WHERE `id` = '$Param[id]'");
//удаление из таблицы элемента с заданным id
if ($Param['id'] == $MaxId[0]) mysqli_query(
  $CONNECT, "ALTER TABLE `load` AUTO_INCREMENT = '$MaxId[0]'");
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы присвоить `auto_increment` значение из переменной. Если заданный `id` будет равен максимальному, то auto_increment должен стать равным ему. Не выполняется. Почему?

Comment: Даже я, в общем то любитель нестандартных решений скажу, что у вас очень странное желание. Предположим у вас в таблице 1000 записей и вероятность удаления любой из них примерно одинакова. Тогда последняя запись будет удалятся с вероятностью 1/1000 и ради чего придумывать механизм экономящий 1 ID из 1000

Comment: То, что делать так нельзя, я и сам знаю. Пожалуйста, помогите конкретно с решением задачи.

Comment: Вы бы тогда сформулировали зачем вам это надо. Может вам вообще автоинкремент не нужен, а просто триггер, который всегда будет назначать id=max()+1

Comment: @GlebOstrikov ваше настойчивое "помогите с решением задачи" один в один напоминает одну [историю](http://phpfaq.ru/humor/anecdotes#surgery)...

Comment: В данном случае не будут нарушаться связи в таблицах или порядок id.

Comment: @GlebOstrikov Только вот одна проблема, alter table работает вне транзакций и вы запросто можете сделать alter на одно число в то время как другой, параллельный процесс запишет запись с этим же числом в таблицу. В итоге при попытке вставке следующей записи вы получите ошибку и с такой таблицей вообще не сможете работать, пока ее руками не исправите. Так что использование автоинкремент колонок в такой схеме вообще недопустимо. _НЕОБХОДИМО_ использовать другие способы назначения ID

Comment: если не будут нарушаться связи в таблицах, то см. пункт 1 моего ответа: автоинкрементный id в этой таблице даром не нужен.

Comment: Я не говорил, что их нет. Они не будут нарушаться. От вас не какой конкретики. Если вам не нравиться мой вопрос, ставьте минус и идите дальше или нормально отвечайте на него. У пользователя cheops достататочно внятный ответ, почему так не надо делать, в отличие от вашего. Но повторяю, мне не надо рассказывать, что так не надо делать, меня интересовал конкретно ответ на мой вопрос.

Comment: @GlebOstrikov Вам все таки стоило сформулировать задачу так, что бы было понятно зачем именно вам это нужно. В 90% случаев есть гораздо более эффективные решения любых задач связанных с неразрывными ID. Не надо зацикливаться на одном единственном решении, тем более потенциально приводящем к проблемам и возможным потерям данных при эксплуатации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $CONNECT, "ALTER TABLE `load` AUTO_INCREMENT = '$MaxId[0]'";

Синтаксическая ошибка:
id - число, а '$MaxId[0]' - приходит строкой!

Comment: Используйте, пожалуйста,стилизацию для вашего ответа и я его обязательно засчитаю.

Answer (score 12):

> При удалении из таблицы элемента с максимальным id, auto_increment должен стать

## Не должен.

Варианта тут только два.

- если в таблице не нужен уникальный идентификатор, то просто убрать это поле.
- если нужен, то его *никогда* не трогаем руками.

Comment: 1)должен стать — это задача, а не предположение.

Comment: Поэтому нужен ответ именно на мой вопрос. Возможно же присвоение константе: ALTER TABLE `load` AUTO_INCREMENT = 7. Интересует вопрос, как auto_increment присвоить переменной?!

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле устанавливать идентификатор `id` с полем `auto_increment` равным `max(id)` строго не рекомендуется. Это поле традиционно используется в качестве значения первичного ключа и главная его задача - быть уникальным. При этом оно может иметь разрывы в нумерации.

Почему так. Представьте большой портал с множеством статей. Вы заводите статью с идентификатором 518010, который попадает в URL данной статьи. Эту статью индексируют роботы поисковых систем, на неё ссылаются с других порталов. Спустя какое-то время вы принимаете решение удалить статью. Однако, если вы займете этот идентификатор другой статьей, все старые ссылки будет вести не на страницу 404, а на совершенно другую статью. Этого не случится, если идентификаторы статей всегда будут уникальны, не будут переиспользовать старые номера, даже если в последовательности будут образовываться разрывы.

В примере у вас `MAX(id)` вычисляется до удаления значения, поэтому SQL-оператор `ALTER TABLE` устанавливает старое значение. Если вы выполните вычисление максимального `id` после удаления - ваш пример заработает, так как вы задумали. Однако, лучше так не делать - это антипаттерн.