# Как обновить колонку autoincrement _id в sql в Android?

Tags: android, sql

При удалении записи удаляется вся row, соответственно порядок в колонке `_id` нарушается. Каким образом можно обновить колонку автоинкремента? Или как то можно особенно удалять, чтобы эта колонка сама обновилась? Может есть какой-то хитрый способ? :)

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что у вас, например идут записи с id: 1, 2, 3, 4; дальше вы удаляете запись с id 3, у вас остаются в базе 1,2,4, а вы хотите, чтобы оставались 1,2,3?

Comment: Возможно дубликат вопроса: [Как присвоить auto\_increment значение переменной?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518010/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-auto-increment-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: Конкретно решение [вашей проблемы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/520280/177345). Костыльное - записывать в модель еще ID записи из БД, потом извлекать его, когда требуется. Правильное - полностью пересмотреть всю архитектуру и работать либо с классами, предназначенными для SQL (`Cursor`, `ContentProvider`, `CursorAdapter`), либо, если так хочется модели, то с ORM. Второй вариант предпочтительнее. Из ORM рекомендую в первую очередь рассмотреть Realm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Изменять значения ID вручную и вообще вмешиваться в автогенерацию этого столбца в таблицах БД **ни в коем случае не следет**, иначе вся ваша БД полетит прямиком в АД.

Никакого хитрого способа тоже нет, каждой новой записи присвается ID последовательно, ID удаленных записей больше не используются.

ID является первичным ключом в таблице и так обеспечивается уникальность идентификаторов записей в таблицах - один из основных принципов построения СУБД. Все взаимодействия с записями в БД построены на этом первичном ключе и если его изменять - начнется хаос.

Вмешательство в значения идентификаторов грозит в частности тем, что будут нарушены все возможные связи БД - один к одному, один ко многим и многие ко многим. Возможно конкретно вы почему то (скорее всего в силу отдаленного знакомства с принципами СУБД) и не используете эти связи, но допустить такое кощунство в БД из-за этого никто не согласится.

Рекомендую ознакомится с принципами и устройством БД и такой дисциплиной, как СУБД, чтобы подобной "ереси" больше не возникало у вас в голове :). Например,  очень доступная книга для начала: *Л. Бейли  - "Изучаем SQL" - 2012*, Серия *"Бестселлеры O'Reilly"* - найти ее довольно легко даже бесплатно.

Comment: а если я поменяю архитектуру на SimpleCursorAdapter, то удаление row не приведет к хаосу в столбце _id? тоесть неужели в адаптере этого типа удаление из 1,2,3,4,5 row с id 3, столбик сам сгенерируется как 1,2,3,4 а не 1,2,4,5?

Comment: @СергейГрушин Классы, предназначенные для работы с *SQLLite*, в частности `CursorAdapter` возвращают помимо позиции еще и ID записи, вам не придется ничего менять в ID, просто вы получите из слушателя корректное значение ID в четвертом параметре `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) ` и сможете его использовать в своей логике. `ArrayAdapter` по понятным причинам (он ничего не знает о БД и ID) этим параметром ничего не возвращает.

Comment: тоесть получив из слушателя id я могу его вставить в запрос к бд для удаления и удаляться все будет нормально?

Comment: @СергейГрушин Да, именно так. Для этого ID и возвращается в слушателе

Comment: отлично, и ещё один вопрос - я же использую собственный адаптер и модель... Можно же будет все оставить, но настроить правильно курсор?

Comment: Нет, вам нужно будет написать новый адаптер на основе `SimpleCursorAdapter`, так как `ArrayAdapter`, который вы сейчас используете, ничего не знает о БД. В реализации `CursorAdapter` есть нюансы, в частности там переопределяется метод `bindView()`, а не `getView()`. Модель вам тоже не понадобится больше, классы для работы с БД используют `Cursor` с выборкой записей. Если вы выбрали в качестве хранилища SQLite, то модели вообще лишнее расточительство ресурсов, здесь правят курсоры.

Comment: у меня в таблице есть колонка list в которой написан id списка которому он принадлежит. В итоге у меня в таблице все продукты из всех списков. Тоесть если в таблице будут продукты из нескольких списков, то отправив в запросе позицию 3 в качестве id, то в БД row с id равным трём, может быть товаром из другого списка. В итоге удалится совсем не то + собьется порядок в колонке id... Вообщем, вот, я все обдумал, нужно срочно поменять адаптер на SimpleCursorAdapter. он же решит проблему в этом комментарие выше?

Comment: В первую очередь вам нужно правильно организовать БД, тогда "не то" никогда не удалится. Организация архитектуры и работа с БД целая дисциплина (СУБД) по которой учебники в тысячи страниц писаны, но перед тем, как продолжать что то писать далее, настоятельно рекомендую прочитать книгу из ответа, чтобы не было потом мучительно больно от напрасно потраченного времени. Так же рекомендую прочитать книгу Б.Харди "Android Программирование для профессионалов" 2015 , там большой и толковый раздел по SQLite и вообще она вам очень сильно поможет в разработке

Comment: насчет bindView я начитан) А вот насчёт модели не совсем понятно... То есть например вот сейчас я заполняю ArrayList<Model> вот так for(int g = 0; g<san.length; g++){
    list.add(new Model(arrTblNames.get(g), arrTblCounts.get(g), (arrTblComplete.get(g)==0)?false:true));
   }

Comment: Вам не нужна будет никакая модель , в адаптер вы передаете курсор и извлекаете информацию непосредственно  из него, не нужны эти пергонки данных из пустого в порожнее. Так же вы можете написать враппер к курсору, который позволит представить данные курсора в виде псевдо-модели - в книге Харди обо все этом подробно написано. Прочитайте книги, что я вам рекомендовал и единственный вопрос, который у вас останется по разработке - почему же я раньше этого не сделал, а писал нелепый код и напрасно тратил время

Comment: Вообще с SQLite одни головняки, вы еще кучу проблем с ней поимеете. Переходите сразу на ORM Realm и множество проблем даже не успеет появится. В частности там очень удобно сделано, что изменения в выборке из БД переданной в адаптер сразу вносятся в саму БД и ничего не надо специально отдельно записывать и беспокоится о сохранении.

Comment: насчет bindView я начитан) А вот насчёт модели не совсем понятно... То есть например вот сейчас я заполняю ArrayList<Model> вот так for(int g = 0; g<san.length; g++){
    list.add(new Model(arrTblNames.get(g), arrTblCounts.get(g), (arrTblComplete.get(g)==0)?false:true));
   }  где я беру данные из трёх других ArrayList-ов, заполненных данными курсором из БД. мне нужно убрать модель, так как нужно будет добавлять данные напрямую курсором, который берёт тип данных со скрипта создания БД из класса враппера.

Comment: книга про связку andtoid - sql? http://spaces.ru/files/view/?Li=41097205568&Lii=3451362305&Link_id=617519&Lt=8&Read=34513623&Sn=2&name=SX228XS&sid=::sid::

Comment: Для формирования требующихся данных в курсоре есть язык sql, он очень мощный и позволяет сформировать  выборку из любых таблиц в один курсор, прямым запросом в БД, а не какими то циклами и перегонами из массива в массив, что выполняется в тысячи раз быстрее. В частности тут и применяются связи в БД. Все это основы работы с БД, я уже устал стучать по клавишам, давайте вы сначала наберетесь каких то необходимых минимальных знаний, а потом вам уже нечего будет спрашивать. Книга не по android - sql, а по организации БД, языку sql и формированию запросов, эти  принципы общие для всех БД.

Comment: вообщем, буду читать ;) спасибо за информацию

Comment: я только сейчас перечитываю какой я бред тогда писал )