# Удаление строки в SQLite по её порядковому номеру

Tags: java, android, sql

Есть некая таблица, в которой сбилась колонка id autoincrement, как можно удалить строку не по её id, а по её порядковому номеру в таблице?

Comment: А вопрос то в чем состоит?

Comment: Зачем ну вот зачем Вам изменять все айди???  Вы представляете себе что это мягко говоря не логично, особенно если в таблице несколько миллионов записей

Comment: @Bulson Мне нужно удалить строку чтобы она как бы сместила все последующие по id, я пытался это сделать но у меня не получалось

Comment: @Victor Приложение небольшое, и мне нужно изменять из-за проблем c адаптером

Comment: Может стоит посмотреть на вопрос по другому. И если очень важен порядковый номер строки, то не изменять айди, а просто считать его тогда, когда он понадобится? Для разумного ответа надо больше информации

Comment: @MaksimHawkins так вам и надо решать проблемы с адаптером, ид записей надо оставить в покое они тут не причем

Comment: @MaksimHawkins так никто не делает. Подумайте о разделении нумерации в таблице данных и нумерации отображаемой, т.е. для UI.

Comment: Лучше разберитесь со своим адаптером, что бы айди не мешало его работе. Задайте новый вопрос по поводу Вашего адаптера и Вашей с ним проблеме. Просто за то что вы спрашиваете в этом вопросе отчаянно "бьют по рукам!"

Comment: Найти нужную строку по порядку. Взять из нее ИД. Удалить по ИД

Answer (score 9, accepted):

При работе с СУБД нет такого понятия, как порядковый номер записи, и нет никаких способов получить его. При правильной организации работы с БД эта информация не потребуется ни при каких возможных действиях с базой.

ID - уникальный идентификатор, а не средство нумерации или упорядочивания в базе. Назначение его -- только однозначно идентифицировать запись (гарантировано отличить одну запись от другой), и если при последовательном добавлении записей ID будет увеличиваться на единицу, то при удалении записи из середины порядок нарушится. Более того, если удалить последнюю запись с ID = 5, к примеру, то при следующем добавлении ID новой записи будет равен 6 - так и должно быть, чтобы структура базы и логика работы с ней не "сломалась". Ни при каких обстоятельствах колонка ID сбиться не может, каждая новая запись автоматически получает число, следующее за использованным ранее - так достигается уникальность.

Ни при каких обстоятельствах клиенту БД не может понадобиться манипулировать ID (менять их значения для конкретной записи, переставлять между записями и т.д.) - необходимость в таких действиях -- верный признак непонимания принципов работы с базой. Попытки это сделать могут привести лишь к проблемам и потере (искажении) хранимых данных.

Если вам потребовались порядковые номера при работе с БД, с большой долей вероятности можно сказать, что вы что-то неправильно делаете, а если вы упорствуете в желании получить эти номера, то вообще не понимаете, что делаете и как нужно работать с БД.

То есть вам нужно сначала научиться работать с базами данных, а потом применять их на практике. СУБД очень сложная и объемная дисциплина, со многими неочевидными моментами, но если знать, как это работает, то никаких проблем и "невозможных" желаний появляться не будет.

Также вам нужно не пытаться удалить запись по порядкову номеру, а начать изучать правильные способы работы с БД.

Начать приобщаться к знаниям рекомендую с книги Линн Бейли "Изучаем SQL" -2012г. Книга написана очень доступно и интересно, в то же время дает полное представление о предмете, в отличии прочей литературы на эту тему - сухой, научной и малодоступной для понимания новичком.

PS: Еще [один ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520733/177345) на похожий вопрос

Comment: *"каждая новая запись автоматически получает следующее число после использованого ранее"* - на самом деле не обязательно. Зависит от типа колонки.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я не могу говорить за все БД, в Android используется SQLite и для колонки ID указывается параметр `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` - при этом происходит именно то, что я написал. Так же существуют легенды, что `AUTOINCREMENT` для колонки помеченной  ключом `PRIMARY KEY` можно не указывать , так как данный ключ уже включает такую функциональность, но не все в нее верят :)

Comment: Вот если `AUTOINCREMENT` не указать - то поведение и изменится. Новая запись будет по-прежнему получать следующее число - но уже без учета удаленных записей.

Comment: А еще можно колонку ID не создавать - тогда она будет называться rowid. И, опять-таки, удаленные записи не будут учитываться.

Comment: Все это есть в документации по SQLite, только ее никто не читает...

Comment: @PavelMayorov  Без AUTOINCREMENT следующий ID будет не на один больше ранее использованного **только в том случае**, если ранее использованный получил значение максимально возможного (предел для положительных чисел типа INTEGER), тогда БД попытается найти неиспользованные числа для ID (но эта деталь в контексте данного вопроса и ответа на него не является сколько-нибудь существенной) Так же в Android столбец, помеченный как PRIMARY KEY может иметь имя только `_id` и никакое иное (не ID, _Id, id и тп.), иначе классы SDK (такие как Cursor) для работы с SQLite, не будут, собственно, работать.

Comment: 1. Это важное отличие. 2. Отделяйте, пожалуйста, SQLite от классов Android SDK для работы с SQLite