# Как я могу сделать постоянно обновляемые id в SQLite на Android'e?

Tags: android, sqlite

Мне нужно, чтобы значения в таблице SQLite соответствовали их позиции даже после удаления элементов.

Например, есть таблица:

```
id name
1  x
2  y
3  d
4  l
...
```

Я хочу, чтобы после удаления строки с id 2 и 3, таблица выглядела вот так:

```
id name
1  x
2  l
...
```

Есть ли какое-либо свойство в SQLite для реализации моей проблемы?

Comment: Изменение id у записи очень плохая практика. Например вы отдаете объект с id=3 клиенту для редактирования, он начинает его править. В это время другой клиент удаляет запись id=2. Первый клиент начинает писать свою запись и она накрывает своими данными ту, которая до этого была с id=4. Так что опишите для чего именно вам это понадобилось, скорее всего есть совершенно другое решение, которое не ставит под удар целостность данных

Comment: Не нужно вам это. Никому не нужно. Хотите красивые подряд идущие индексы - нумеруйте их на клиенте. Всё.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87 Здесь доступно описаны все преймущества статичности ид.

Comment: то, что вы спрашиваете - это за пределами добра и зла работы с базой данных, никто, немного понимающий СУБД, в здравом уме на такое не пойдет, хоть, может лично вам эта идея и кажется великолепной. id - это уникальный идентификатор, а не порядковый счетчик, как фамилия  у вас, как вам идея менять всем фамилии, когда кто то помрет? ответ- на ваш вопрос - никак. базам данных вообще очень редко нужны порядковые счетчики и тот факт, что вам это понадобилось, говорит о том, что с большой долей вероятности вы все делаете неправильно.

Comment: опишите в вопросе,  какая у вас проблема, а не помощь в вашем заведомо неправильном ее решении. смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606454/177345) с пояснениями почему делать, как вы хотите ни в коем случае нельзя

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Решил проблему, сделав это программно. Я просто хотел уникальный счетчик позиций сделать. То есть, id чтобы выступал не как уникальный идентификатор, а просто нумеровал строки в таблице.