# Как удалить строку из SQLite базы с сохранением последовательности ID?

Tags: android, sqlite

Имеется метод, который удаляет строку в бд:

```
public void deleteAlarmItem(AlarmItem alarmItem) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.delete(Util.TABLE_NAME, Util.KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] {
            String.valueOf(alarmItem.getId())
    });

    db.close();
}
```

И метод удаления элемента интерфейса из RecyclerView:

```
public void deleteAlarmClock(int position) {
    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    AlarmItem alarmItem = databaseHandler.getAlarmItems(position);
    databaseHandler.deleteAlarmItem(alarmItem);

    Log.i("position", "" + position);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cancelAlarm();
}
```

По моему представлению, при удалении элемента интерфейса под номером 1, автоматически должна удаляться строка с таким же идентификатором.

Но после удаления строк (например 2 и 5), последовательность ID нарушается, вместо 1234 получается 1346. И в последующих попытках удалить элемент интерфейса приложение крашится.

Подскажите как можно сохранять последовательность ID при удалении или добавлении строк в БД.

Comment: У вас неправильная логика в моменте связи БД<->Интерфейс. То что он первый в списке не означает что его идентификатор = 1. З.Ы. лучше сразу думать в верном направлении нежели искать костыли для работы по "вашей" логике.

Comment: Вот я и хочу исправить логику связи БД и Интерфейса. RecyclerView за первый объект в списке выдает 0, как я думал БД поступает также, но после удаления элемента интерфейса, RecyclerView сортирует свой список ID элементов (до удаления 1 и 4 012345, после 0123), а вот SQLite делает так (до удаления 1 и 4 012345, после 0235).

Comment: Вы прочли мой комментарий по диагонали, SQLite - нумерует верно, RecyclerView - тоже нумерует верно. Вы удаляете "НЕВЕРНО". Связывать элемент базы данных по PKey с массивом(списком) по порядковому номеру - **НЕВЕРНО**.

Comment: Правильное решение это хранить в RecyclerView объекты, у которых одно из полей =KEY_ID, и при удалении записи из RecyclerView, использовать это поле для удаления записи из SQLite

Comment: `AlarmItem alarmItem = databaseHandler.getAlarmItems(position);` - проблема в этой строке, вы берёте `alarmItem` из базы по позиции в адаптере, но для правильной работы должны его взять из адаптера. Если адаптер у вас отображает другую модель, то в этой модели должно быть поле с `id` из базы и удаление нужно делать по нему.

Comment: дело в том, что ID в БД это не порядковый номер, а уникальный идентификатор, который гарантирует, что по нему вы обратитесь всегда к одной и той же записи. Как  паспортные данные у человека - никто не меняет всем паспорта, чтобы были по порядку, если человека не станет. Таким образом сохранять последовательность ID при удалении записи в корне неправильное решение. Вам надо что то почитать о теории СУБД, прежде чем с ней работать

Comment: связанный вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606454/177345

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, понял что несу чушь, буду разбираться дальше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение!

Сразу скажу что этот вариант не претендует на правильное решение так как я еще учусь и мне дается с трудом, но все работает без проблем. Буду рад если вы подправите этот код.

В RecyclerView адаптере, в методе onBindViewHolder передал для itemView тэг с ID из бд:

```
if (!cursor.moveToPosition(i)) {
        return;
    }

    long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Util.KEY_ID));
    viewHolder.itemView.setTag(id);
```

Тем самым указав тот самый уникальный идентификатор для элемента RecyclerView.
После чего в интерфейсе OnItemClickListener передал объект класса View и позицию элемента:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

И уже в основном Activity, управляя нажатием на CardView обновляю интерфейс и удаляю запись из бд:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            deleteAlarmClock((long) view.getTag());
            Toast.makeText(AlarmActivity.this, "Alarm deleted at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

public void deleteAlarmClock(long id) {
    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    databaseHandler.deleteAlarmItem(id);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    cancelAlarm();
}
```