# Функция adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position) игнорируется (?)

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

В моём проекте есть фрагмент показывающий список элементов. Следующая часть кода должна отвечать за удаление выбранного элемента:

```
fun delete(position: Int) {

        database.roomDao().delete(position)//удаление элемента из базы данных

        for (i in position..(database.roomDao().getAll().size)){//обновление id для оставшихся элементов
            database.roomDao().updateId(i+1.toLong(),i.toLong())
        }

        itemsList.removeAt(position)//удаление элемента из arrayList

        myAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)//должен был динамически удалить данный элемент из RecyclerView

        myAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, myAdapter.itemCount)

    }
```

До этого момента `myAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)` всё работает ожидаемо, элемент удаляется из базы данных и array list. Однако, элемент не удаляется динамически. Изменения видны только тогда, когда я открываю фрагмент заново. Кажется что эта часть кода не работает по какой либо причине. Android Studio даже не выдаёт никаких ошибок. Почему так происходит? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Видимо вы удаляете не из того списка, что используется в адаптере. Покажите как и где вы передаёте данные в адаптер и откуда у вас itemsList, из которого вы удаляете. И да, изменение ID в таблице, как и удаление не по ID, а по позиции - очень сомнительное решение. Лучше делать так: 1. Получить из БД список - передать его в адаптер. 2. Удалять не по позиции, а по ID. 3. Реактивно получить изменённый список из БД и его элементы передать в список адптера. 4. Опционально использовать DiffUtil для уведомления адаптера об изменениях в списке.

Comment: Вот:
    lateinit var itemsList: ArrayList<Model>
    lateinit var list: List<Model>
    suspend fun sincData() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            list = database.roomDao().getAll()


        }
        itemsList = ArrayList<Model>(list)

        myAdapter.sinc(itemsList)
    }

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос - в комменте он почти нечитаем. Также покажите что у вас внутри `myAdapter.sinc(itemsList)`

Comment: Для начала вам стоит [прочитать этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606454/177345) и понять, что нужно решать более глобальную проблему прямо сейчас. Нет никакого смысла разбираться с какой то мелкой неприятностью, когда у вас глобальные проблемы в организации работы приложения

Comment: `fun sinc(newList: ArrayList<Model>) { list = newList }` Эта функция только передаёт  list в Adapter класс

Comment: @pavloff, спасибо за объяснение. Я понял какую кашу натворил