# Как очистить primary key в таблице?

Tags: android, база-данных, android-studio, sqlite

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я несколько раз удалял (или очищал) таблицу командой DROP TABLE IF EXISTS..., но, несмотря на то, что записей всего 3, primary key (_id) ведёт отсчёт не с 1
Как его можно обнулить?

Вот код DBHelper, в котором создаю базу данных

```
package com.nikitafront.androidlearning;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "users";

public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_LOGIN= "_login";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "_password";

public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_LOGIN + " TEXT, "
            +  KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT"
            +  ");");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

Comment: *primary key (_id) ведёт отсчёт не с 1* Почему Вас это заботит? Если нужен порядковый номер записи в таблице - есть ROWID.

Comment: Возможно, вам нужно ознакомиться с этой информацией, прежде чем производить манипуляции с primary key: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606454/177345

Answer (score 0):

`db.execSQL("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.table_name', RESEED, 1)");`

Comment: Вопрос помечен тегом SQLite.

Comment: @Akina тогда удалить таблицу которая хранит счетчик для таблицы ```DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = 'table_name';```

Comment: В ответ это, в ответ... вместо неприменимого совета.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Так как я перебирал все записи в главном файле через класс cursor, я просто воспользовался методом класса getCount(), который мне выдал номер строки (спасбио за подсказку пользователю Akina)

А сбросить счётчик _id помогло удаление таблицы через "DROP TABLE", а затем удаление файлов бд из файловой системы эмулятора