# Обновление и "сортировка" auto increment field в базе данных Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Добрый день!
Использую SQLite DB в Android приложении и первое поле - Auto increment, ID объектов. При удалении, нужно чтоб последующие ID становились меньше (т.е. были в верном порядке цифровом), как можно реализовать данный вопрос ?

Comment: Пересмотрите вариант решения Вашей задачи. Так делать просто незачем.

Comment: Смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520733/177345).Поле id это не счетчик позиций. БД вообще не использует понятия позиций в записях и если они вам понадобились, то вы делаете все неправильно скорее всего. Опишите саму решаемую задачу (для чего вам понадобилось менять id), а не ваш [неправильный] способ ее решения (как менять id)

Answer (score 0):

У каждой записи в таблице SQLite есть имплицитное поле ROWID. Когда вы делаете запрос VACUUM, эти поля как раз переформируются нужным вам образом. Только не понятно, зачем это нужно.

Comment: Как-то слишком сложно вы написали:( У меня в базе хранятся контакты, есть активность где они выводятся.. вот на активности пользователь выбирает контакт, я получаю его порядковый номер на активности и делаю удаление по его номеру в базе, потому что они соответствуют. Вот только после удаления.. надо чтоб те что были выше него - поменяли айди.

Comment: Ну вот смотрите. У вас есть последняя запись с PRIMARY KEY 1000 и предпоследняя 999. Вы удаляете запись 999. Вы хотите, чтобы следующий INSERT автоматически использовал ID 999 вместо 1001?

Comment: Я удаляю 999, хочу чтоб 1000 запись стала на её место с ид=999, а последующая добавленная занимала уже 1000.

Comment: Так делать нельзя, поскольку какая-то запись в другой таблице БД может ссылаться на ту, которой вы хотите изменить ключ, и ссылаться она будет именно по ключу. При его изменении связь между записями в разных таблицах будет нарушена.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, но это чисто моя база данных.

Comment: Тогда делайте VACUUM после каждого INSERT и используйте ROWID вместо ID. Но так делать нельзя. Это наверняка решается другими способами.